# R: Confidence intervals on non-linear fit with a non-analytic model

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

I need to fit x-y data with a model, which is non-analytic. I have a function `f(x)` that calculates the model for each `x` numerically, but there is no analytical equation. For the fit, I use `optim` in R. I minimise RMS between the model and the data. It works well and returns reasonable parameters.

I would like to find confidence intervals (or at least standard errors) on the best-fitting parameters. I found on internet that this can be done from the Hessian matrix, but only if maximising log-likelihood function. I don't know how to do this, all I have is `x`, `y` and `f(x)` from which I find RMS. Alas, I have no good way of estimating errors on `y`.

How can I find confidence intervals on my fit parameters?

Edit: perhaps an example in R might help explaining what I'm asking for. This example uses a simple analytic function to fit the data, in my real case the function is non-analytic, so I cannot use, e.g., `nls`.

```
set.seed(666)

# generate data
x <- seq(100) / 100
y <- 0.5 * x + rnorm(100, sd = 0.03) + 0.2

# function to fit
f <- function(x, a, b) {
  a * x + b
}

# error function to minimise: RMS
errfun <- function(par, x, y) {
  a <- par[1]
  b <- par[2]
  err <- sqrt(sum((f(x, a, b) - y)^2))
}

# use optim to fit the model to the data
par <- c(1, 0)
res <- optim(par, errfun, gr=NULL, x, y)

# best-fitting parameters
best_a <- res$par[1]
best_b <- res$par[2]
```

The best fitting parameters are a = 0.50 and b = 0.20. I need to find 95% confidence intervals on these.

Comment: If there is no (easy) analytical expression for the likelihood, you are probably better using a (nonparametric) bootstrap. Calculate f(x*) for many different x* which are sampled with replacement from x.

Comment: How do I find confidence intervals from the bootstrap? I wasn't very clear with my definitions, the function I fit to the data is f(x; a, b, c), where a, b and c are model parameters.

Comment: I've turned it into a full answer. Hopefully that is more helpful (assuming you are using the standard notation of `y` being the outcome, `x` being the data, `f(x)` being some sort of estimator and `a,b,c` being independent model parameters (e.g. number of iterations) that don't depend on `x`).

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for the bootstrap:

(1) create a large number of synthetic datasets `x*`. These are created by sampling from `x` with replacement the same number of data as were in `x`. For example, if your data is `(1,2,3,4,5,6)` an `x*` might be `(5,2,4,4,2,3)` (note that values might appear multiple times, or not at all because we are sampling with replacement)

(2) For each `x*`, calculate `f(x*)`. If there are other parameters which don't depend on the data, don't change them. (so `f(x,a,b,c)` becomes `f(x*,a,b,c)` as long as `a,b,c` don't depend on `x`. Call these quantities `f*`.

(3) You can estimate anything you want from these `f*`. If you want the standard deviation of `f(x)`, take the standard deviation of `f*`. If you want the 95% confidence interval, take the range from the 2.5 to the 97.5 percentiles of `f*`. More formally, if you want to estimate `g(f(x))` you estimate it as `g(f(x*))`.

I should say this is a very practically-oriented explanation of the bootstrap. I have glossed over many theoretical details, but the bootstrap is near-universally applicable (basically as long as the thing you are trying to estimate actually *exists*, you are usually okay).

To apply this to the example you have given in your code:

```
x <- seq(100) / 100
y <- 0.5 * x + rnorm(100, sd = 0.03) + 0.2

# function to fit
f <- function(x, a, b) {
  a * x + b
}

# error function to minimise: RMS
errfun <- function(par, x, y) {
  a <- par[1]
  b <- par[2]
  err <- sqrt(sum((f(x, a, b) - y)^2))
}

# this is the part where we bootstrap
# use optim to fit the model to the data
best_a <- best_b <- numeric(10000)
for(i in 1:10000){
  j <- sample(100,replace=TRUE)
  x.boot <- x[j]; y.boot <- y[j]
par <- c(1, 0)
res <- optim(par, errfun, gr=NULL, x.boot, y.boot)

# best-fitting parameters
best_a[i] <- res$par[1]
best_b[i] <- res$par[2]
}
# now, we look at the *vector* best_a
# for example, if you want the standard deviation of a,
sd(best_a)
# or a 95% confidence interval for b,
quantile(best_b,c(0.025,0.975))
```

Comment: Thank you, JDL. This is a very clear explanation. However, I need confidence intervals on fit parameters, a, b and c. That is, apart from the best-fitting a, I need a_lo and a_up, which are, e.g., 95% CI for a.

Comment: Then these are part of the results of `f(x)`. By putting them in the brackets it looks like they are user-specified. `f(x)` is allowed to have multiple elements in it.

Comment: Sorry, I still cannot see how bootstrapping x can help me with my problem. I extended the question to include a simple example. Perhaps you could explain how to apply bootstrap on this example.

Comment: Ah! I see now! It is sampling with replacement from data (x, y), fitting each sample and finding parameters a* and b*. I have done quite a bit of bootstrapping in my life, but haven't seen this approach. But now I see that this makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot for your effort!

Comment: Glad to be of help :)